# Rating mechanisms

Tags: rating

Is there any place that showcases a bunch of different types of rating systems (like using multiple sliders, star ratings, up/down votes)? I'm trying to get ideas for a better rating system than just up/down (more criteria).

(I'm not interested in the backend, but the human/computer interaction part of it).

Comment: You are currently using a site with a quite good rating system :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://blog.steepster.com/post/226679106/better-rating-system